# Solving $\log_{x/2}(x+2)-\log_x(4-x)=1$

Tags: logarithms

> $$\bbox[aqua]{\log _{\frac{x}{2}}(x+2)-\log _x(4-x)=1}$$

$$\mapsto \log _{\frac{x}{2}}(x+2)=\log _x x+\log _x(4-x) 
\\\Rightarrow \log _{\frac{x}{2}}(x+2)=\log _x(x(4-x)) 
\\\Rightarrow \frac{\log _x(x+2)}{\log _x\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}=\log _x(x(4-x)) 
\\\Rightarrow \log _x(x+2)=\log _x(x(4-x)) \log _x\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) \\\Rightarrow \color{\red}{x+2=x^{\log _x(x(4-x)) \log _x\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}} \Rightarrow \, ? ? ?
$$

The equation is marked in blue, I also wrote my solution attached to the equation, but when I got to the red part, I ran into trouble from there on and could not find a way to find the answer to $x$. I would like to know what your solution is.

Comment: Where did this equation come from?

Comment: @Claude Leibovici, I meant that $x≈0.4548$ is a solution.

Comment: If $x=2^{-w}$, then $2^{w+2}+2=(4-2^{-w})^{\frac1w+1}$. Is there any way to reduce the equation?